# JAXB Soap Service Runtime Error (XPath method not found)

Tags: java, soap, xpath, service, jaxb

I am creaing a soap based web service with JAXB and Spring framework to throw it all together. I am generating the wsdl file dynamically using spring's web services but when I try and access it, I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(Z)V
at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:115)
at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:99)
at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:184)
at org.springframework.xml.xpath.Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory$Jaxp13XPathExpression.evaluate(Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory.java:114)
at org.springframework.xml.xpath.Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory$Jaxp13XPathExpression.evaluateAsNodeList(Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory.java:106)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter.transformLocations(WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter.java:200)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter.handle(WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter.java:128)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
```

Now first of all, I have never seen (Z)V at the end of a NoSuchMethodError before so I am unsure what that means, but I am also getting a very limited stack trace here. I also do not understand how a class in the same project could call a method that does not exist. If anyone has some ideas as to where I should start looking to resolve this, that would be great. More information can of course be provided upon request.

EDIT:

So using the mvn depedency:tree command to see if there are mutiple jars with different versions of xpath I get the following output:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ LicensingSOAPService ---
[INFO] com.cepstral.licensing:LicensingSOAPService:war:0.1
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.wsit:xws-security:jar:1.3.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.wsit:wsit-rt:jar:1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.8:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.3:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
[INFO] |     +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |        +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
```

I do not see anything suspicious, so I am not really sure where else to go. I am continuing to try and use the -verbose option of glassfish to trace errors. Thanks everyone.

Edit 2: So in the glassfish log it shows the following:

```
[Loaded org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xpath.XPathContext from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.dtm.ObjectFactory$ConfigurationError from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMException from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMConfigurationException from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.dtm.DTM from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xalan.extensions.ExpressionContext from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.utils.ObjectStack from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.utils.IntVector from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.xml.utils.IntStack from file:/C:/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/licensingSoap/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.6.0.jar]
```

which shows for sure that somewhere the xalan-2.6.0 jar is being loaded, but when I look in the target\licensingSoap folder of my maven project, there is only the xalan-2.7.1 jar which I am assuming is the one I want. I have no idea how this jar is cropping up at runtime on glassfish. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably be picking up the wrong version of a class file from somewhere.
Re-run with -verbose:class to see where all these classes are loaded from.
If you need help interpretting the results, please post the results here (if you can - dunno what size you're allowed!).

HTH,

David

Comment: You mean use -verbose:class in the JVM variables in my glassfish container?

Comment: Yep, if it's Glassfish you're using you'll get quite a lot of output, but you should be able to search it for the classnames you're having problems with

Comment: You'll have to Google that one, but essentially using that -verbose:class you can check where the classes in your stack trace are loaded from. Then you can hopefully figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: So you were right, an older version of xalan was in the glassfish application folder. I deleted the entire folder, redeployed and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problems , glad you got it sorted